# For an entire function $f(z)$, is it true that $f(z)=f(\bar{z})$ for all complex $z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, entire-functions

I know that $f(z)$ is entire so I can write it as Taylor series:
$f(z)=\sum c_n z^n=\sum Re(c_n)z^n+i\sum Im(c_n)z^n$

from above we see this:

$\overline{f(z)}=\sum c_n z^n=\sum Re(c_n)z^n-i\sum Im(c_n)z^n$

(Pay attention for the minus!)

and this:

$f(\bar{z})=\sum c_n \bar{z}^n=\sum Re(c_n)\bar{z}^n+i\sum Im(c_n)\bar{z}^n$

after playing with some algebra i found that $f(\bar{z})$ equals to $\overline{\overline{f(z)}}=f(z)$

it sound strange, someone can tell me if it is really true for entire $f(z)$ for every complex $z$ ?

**EDIT**

ok I see that it is no true, but what about $|f(\bar{z})|$ ? is it equals to absolute value of something? maybe $|\overline{f(z)}|$ ?

Comment: Take $f(z)=z$ as a counterexample.

Comment: In your formula for $f(z)$, you broke $c_n$ into real and imaginary parts, but you totally forgot to do the same thing with $z^n$. That is, you treated $z$ as real.

Comment: No, just consider $f(z)=z=x+iy$. Then $f(\overline{z})=\overline{z}=x-iy$. Your mistake was isolating $z^n$ from Re$(c_n)$ ( and the same with the imaginary part)

Comment: Even simpler, take $f(z)=i$.

Comment: $|f(\bar{z})|=\left|\overline{\bar{f}(z)}\right|=|\bar{f}(z)|$, where the function $\bar{f}$ is defined by $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$. This is tautological, but it might allow you to work with an analytic function $\bar{f}(z)$ instead of an anti-analytic $f(\bar{z})$.

Comment: and it's not true that  $|f(\bar{z})|=|\overline{\bar{f}(z)}|=|f(z)|$ ?

Comment: @wind Your question was edited because you originally asked a question, then removed it and asking a new one. It's not a good practice to do this because you could invalidate the already given answers. If you come up with a _new_ question, simply ask a new question or **edit** the current question like it is now

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not true. Just take $f(z)=iz$, which is an entire function.

Note that$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n\implies\overline{f(z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\overline{c_n}\,\overline z^n.$$

Comment: what can you tell about $|f(\bar{z})|$ ? to what it equals ? (when $f(z)$ is entire)

Comment: I am not aware of any simple expression for $\left\lvert f\left(\overline z\right)\right\rvert$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=z+i$. Then $f(\overline z)=\overline z+i$. There is no particular relation bewteen

$$|f(z)|^2=x^2+(y+1)^2$$ and $$|f(\overline z)|^2=x^2+(y-1).$$